# Elmah ignore System.Web.HttpException (0x80072746)

Tags: elmah

I try to ignore the System.Web.HttpException (0x80072746) in Elmah. I tried the following, but they don't work:

```
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="0x80072746" type="UInt32" />
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```

and

```
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="0x80072746" type="Int32" />
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```

and

```
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="0x80072746" type="String" />
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```

I've found this thread, but it tells me to cast it... I don't know how to cast it in Elmah Config:
[How to catch a specific HttpException (#0x80072746) in an IHttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104843/how-to-catch-a-specific-httpexception-0x80072746-in-an-ihttphandler)

Does anyone has a idea?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not HTTP status codes you're testing for, they're ASP.Net Error codes. HTTP Status codes are three digits like 404 (Not Found) or 500 (Internal Server Error). To ignore .Net errors like those specified, you could try a match using RegEx on the error message like below:

```
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <regex binding="BaseException.Message" pattern="System.Web.HttpException (0x80072746)" />
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```